# Sync time of all clients with server

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

> **Sync time of all clients with server**

I have a client server architecture project. I want to correct client machine time if it is out of sync with the server's time. 
Should i write a thread which will check server's time and accordingly adjust its own time after fixed interval or is there any other way ?

Comment: Use ntp in the underlying operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) on the server and client OS settings.

Why do you need the sychronized time? If you need sychronized content: How about using internal version numbers instead of timestamps?